# Cope with spatial auto-correlation by using mixed models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, autocorrelation, spatial, lme4-nlme

I have the following spatial-temproal dataset and I want to find out which of my estimator variables (bio 8,9,16,17) are significant in explaining production:

```
> head(RegrInput)
DistrID Year Production        bio8        bio9      bio16      bio17
1       1 1982   1433.833  0.17695395  0.00240241  -18.73348  24.933607
2       1 1983   1151.877 -0.06570671 -0.56608232   19.08482  12.682994
3       1 1984   1317.626  0.48731404  0.64346423 -113.17526 -33.892477
...
```

There are 65 districts (DistrID) and 34 years. The problem is that the estimators are spatially auto-correlated. So, they will be similar in neighboring districts. I heard that in such case, the p values of a linear model (written in R)

```
 lm(Production ~ bio8 + bio9...)
```

cannot be trusted. I heard that a mixed linear model like

```
 lme(Production ~ bio8 + bio9...,random=~1|DistrID)
```

can resolve this problem. I know that the latter uses a different intercept for each district. I do not have a deep statistics knowledge. My question is whether the p values can be interpreted as usual now and why this is so?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Felix